# what do you call this design pattern Polymer and Backbone use for parameters

Tags: javascript

In Polymer and Backbone.js I was digging through the source to find out how they organize their API's for the user.
Currently I'm using a revealing pattern and runs NAMESPACE.init(args) but I liked the way those two libs are making you set everything in the ready or attached methods as callback functions but I don't know the name to do some more research on it with.

Example: I call Polymer and assign something into its ready method as a callback function, I assume it's just overwriting an internal ready method and it stores it for later.
Backbone looks mostly the same

```
Polymer({
   ready: function() {
        console.log("im ready like!")
   }
});
```

Comment: An options dictionary with an attached callback function?

Comment: rather long name. I thought there might be some popular name like "Save Assigner" or something the like, something that can be searched on. But thank you.

Comment: You can't identify a design pattern by it's name only from a function call, in your example the global function `Polymer` is being called which accepts an object as argument but it doesn't tell anything about it's underlying implementation. You may [read this](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript). Could be the module pattern tho.

Comment: What this is demonstrating is object *extending* through optional object parameters passed in the constructor that typically override defaults. For want of a better example, see [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you all. It looks to be a new adventure to read into!

Answer (score 0):

Perfect I guesss..
using underscore.js extend function rather then jquerys in this example but I guess jquery would work all the same.

```
Tacos = function (args) {
    this.commands = {
        popcorn : function(){
            console.log("pop'n fun!");
        },
        render : function(){
            vars.mine = args.cat;
        }
    }
    // using underscore.js _.extend function
    // this merges the commands and replaces the popcorn function with
    // the users function! Fun!
    _.extend(this.commands, args);

}
var u = new Tacos({
    popcorn : function(){
        console.log("popcorn denied a tron! ");
    }
});

u.commands.popcorn()// should return "popcorn denied a tron!"
```